# What is the definition of a Hekesh?

Tags: halacha-theory, midrash

I'm having trouble finding the true definition of a Hekesh. If possible, could someone please define it, and possibly provide an example?
- I'm asking in the sense of comparing biblical texts, (I have a class test on the halachic/aggadic midrash).

I am looking for an explanation of the idea; not the etymology of the word hekesh.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for the etymology of the word hekesh, or for an explanation of the idea?

Comment: I am looking for an explanation of the idea

Comment: If you learn the gemoro in  aizehu mekomon, it discusses hekesh gezairo shovo kal v'chomer binyan ov. And if you have one can you further learn something else from it. For instance if you have a hekesh can you learn a further hekesh (not in kodshim) or any of the other 3 from it. Daf yomi will soon be up to zevochim after pesach.

Answer (score 4):

A hekesh is a type of Talmudic derivation in which a known law from one case is applied to another case. This is generally on the basis of the two cases appearing in the same Scriptural verse. This is perhaps best stated by Tosafos in [Sukkah 31a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=31&format=pdf) (ד"ה ור"י)

> היקישא דהיינו שני דברים המוקשים בפסוק אחד

The exact methodology/rules for making hekeishim is not entirely crystallized, and thus we find some lengthy discussions about the viability and/or parameters of specific hekeshim. For example, the Talmud in [Kiddushin 5a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=5&format=pdf) spends quite a few lines discussing a potential hekesh from the verse which mentions divorce and marriage.

> ומנין שאף בשטר ודין הוא ומה כסף שאין מוציא מכניס שטר שמוציא אינו דין
>   שמכניס מה לכסף שכן פודין בו הקדש ומעשר שני תאמר שטר שאין פודין בו הקדש
>   ומעשר שני דכתיב ונתן הכסף וקם לו אמר קרא ויצאה והיתה מקיש הויה ליציאה
>   מה יציאה בשטר אף הויה נמי בשטר ואקיש נמי יציאה להויה מה הויה בכסף אף
>   יציאה בכסף אמר אביי יאמרו כסף מכניס כסף מוציא סניגור יעשה קטיגור אי
>   הכי שטר נמי יאמרו שטר מוציא שטר מכניס קטיגור יעשה סניגור מילי דהאי
>   שטרא לחוד ומילי דהאי שטרא לחוד הכא נמי האי כספא לחוד והאי כספא לחוד
>   טיבעא מיהא חד הוא רבא אמר אמר קרא וכתב לה בכתיבה מתגרשת ואינה מתגרשת
>   בכסף ואימא בכתיבה מתגרשת ואינה מתקדשת בכתיבה הא כתיב ויצאה והיתה מקיש
>   וכו' ומה ראית מסתברא קאי בגירושין ממעט גירושין קאי בגירושין וממעט
>   קידושין
>
> And whence do we know that [a woman may be acquired] by deed too? But
>   may it not be inferred a minori: if money, which cannot free, effects
>   betrothal; then deed, which frees, can surely tie? — [No.] As for
>   money, that is because hekdesh and second tithe can be redeemed
>   therewith; can you say likewise of a deed, by which hekdesh and second
>   tithe cannot be redeemed, for it is written, [and if he that
>   sanctified the field will in any wise redeem it,] then he shall add
>   the fifth part of the money of thy estimation, and it shall be assured
>   to him. Therefore Scripture saith, And when she is departed [out of
>   his house, she may go] and be [another man's wife]: thus ‘be — coming’
>   [betrothed] is assimilated to ‘departure’ [divorce]; just as the
>   ‘departure’ is by deed, so is ‘becoming’ too. Then let ‘departure be
>   assimilated to ‘becoming’: just as the ‘becoming’ may be by money, so
>   the ‘departure’ too may be effected by money? — Abaye replied: Then it
>   will be said: Money unites and money sunders: shall the defender
>   become the prosecutor! If so, of deed too it will be said: Deed
>   sunders and deed unites: shall the prosecutor become the defender! —
>   The contents of each deed are distinct. Then here too, [the purpose
>   of] this money is distinct and that of the other is distinct? —
>   Nevertheless, the impress [of the coin] is the same. Raba said:
>   Scripture saith, then he shall write her [a writ of divorcement]:
>   [hence], she can be divorced by writing, not by money. Say rather, she
>   can be divorced by ‘writing’, but not betrothed by writing? — But it
>   is written, and when she is departed, she may go and be, etc.,
>   assimilating etc. And why do you choose thus? — It is logical: when
>   treating of divorce, one excludes [a particular method of] divorce;
>   but when dealing with divorce, shall one exclude [a form of] marriage?
>   [Surely not!] ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/nashim/Kiddushin.pdf).)

An example of a hekesh that compares two cases that are in separate verses, is the hekesh mentioned in [Berachos 20b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=20b&format=pdf) from which we derive that women are obligated in the positive aspects of Shabbos.

> אמר רב אדא בר אהבה נשים חייבות בקדוש היום דבר תורה אמאי מצות עשה שהזמן
>   גרמא הוא וכל מצות עשה שהזמן גרמא נשים פטורות אמר אביי מדרבנן א"ל רבא
>   והא דבר תורה קאמר ועוד כל מצות עשה נחייבינהו מדרבנן אלא אמר רבא אמר
>   קרא זכור ושמור כל שישנו בשמירה ישנו בזכירה והני נשי הואיל ואיתנהו
>   בשמירה איתנהו בזכירה
>
> R. Adda b. Ahabah said: Women are under obligation to sanctify the
>   [Sabbath] day by ordinance of the Torah. But why should this be? It
>   is a positive precept for which there is a definite time, and women
>   are exempt from all positive precepts for which there is a definite
>   time? — Abaye said: The obligation is only Rabbinical. Said Raba to
>   him: But it says, ‘By an ordinance of the Torah’? And further, on this
>   ground we could subject them to all positive precepts by Rabbinical
>   authority? Rather, said Raba. The text says Remember and Observe.
>   Whoever has to ‘observe’ has to ‘remember’; and since these women have
>   to ‘observe’, they also have to ‘remember’. ([Soncino translation.](https://halakhah.com/pdf/zeraim/Berachoth.pdf))

As explained by [R. Ezekiel Landau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechezkel_Landau) in his [commentary](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19254&st=&pgnum=60), this is a hekesh even though the two cases are not in the same verse because "zachor" and "shamor" were said by God in one utterance.

> ועוד כל מצות עשה נחייבינהו מדרבנן. ויש לדקדק א"כ תיקשי לרב אדא בר אהבה
>   למה הוצרך לומר דבר תורה והוה ליה למימר סתם נשים חייבות בקידוש היום
>   וממילא שמעינן דהיינו מן התורה דאי מדרבנן א"כ כל מצות עשה נחייבינהו
>   מדרבנן ונראה דלאביי דלא אסיק אדעתא הך הקישא דזכור ושמור **שבאמת אין
>   היקש זה דומיא דשאר הקישות שהם כתובים יחד אבל זכור ושמור רחוקים הם זה
>   כתיב בדברות הראשונות בפרשת יתרו וזה כתיב בדברות שבמשנה תורה אלא שאעפ"כ
>   דרשינן להו בהיקש דשניהם בדיבור אחד נאמרו** ואביי דלא אסיק אדעתא הך
>   הקישא שפיר הקשה לו רבא א"כ כל מצות עשה נחייבינהו מדרבנן דמאי אולמא דהך
>   עשה דקידוש היום משאר מצות עשה שהזמן גרמא אבל רבא שחידש לנו הך הקישא
>   ובזה יש מקום לטעות ולומר שאין לדרוש היקש הזה וכמ"ש **שאין זה דומה לשאר
>   היקש שבתורה** והיה מקום לומר דחכמים חייבינהו לנשים בקידוש היום דחששו
>   שמא יטעו לומר דזכור ושמור איתקשו ויאמרו הני נשי הואיל וליתניהו בזכירה
>   ליתניהו בשמירה ואף דכתיב בקרא אתה ובנך ובתך וגו' ואמתך וגו' איכא למימר
>   היינו שהאב מוזהר עליהם כשם שמוזהר על שביתת בהמתו אבל הם בעצמם אינן
>   מוזהרות ולכך כדי שלא יבואו למיטעי ויבא מזה חילול שבת לכך גזרו חכמים
>   עליהם וחייבו אותם גם במצות עשה דזכור דהיינו קידוש היום ולעולם שהוא
>   מדרבנן ולכך הוצרך רב אדא לומר דבר תורה **להורות שהוא היקש גמור וניתן
>   לדרוש ככל שאר היקש שבתורה**

[R. Yair Chaim Bachrach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yair_Bacharach) states ([Shu"t Chavos Yair # 203](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=857&pgnum=230)) that some hekeishim are just asmachtos, meaning that the Sages already knew the law in question but they just attached it to the particular wording of the verse.

> ויש דאינם כלל משום רמז והוכחה רק דילפי דבר מדבר מסברא וברובם יש
>   פלוגתת' כגון הא דפסחים ריש ס"ד וסוכה ל"א ע"א ושבת צ"ז ע"א ובמשנה
>   עירוכין פ"ד מ"ד וע"ע פי' רש"י סנהדרין פ"ה ע"א רק דרז"ל סמכו קבלתם
>   האמיתית על רמז היקש מה כמ"ש מטות מקיש מטה אם למטה אב בב"ב ד' קי"א ע"א
>   וע"ע בכה"ג מס' ר"ה ר"ד ל"ד ויבמות ס"ט ע"א

There are many other technical details related to hekeishim, and probably the best place to get an overview would be the entry for hekesh in the Encyclpedia Talmudit.

Comment: great work! but just to be honest, i was discouraged by the length of the article. I wrote a short answer instead, i hope you don't mind.

Comment: Isn't a heqesh among the 13 middos shehaTorah nidreshes bahen as a subtype of gezeira shava? And if so, mention of the fact would belong in the answer.

Comment: Also, you open with "[a]n example of a hekesh that compares two cases that are in separate verses"and then give the Tziun leNefesh Chayah's explanation of why "Shamor" and "Zakhor" are a special case. Or perhaps the first and second versions of the diberos are special. Either case, not a generality of which this is an example.

Comment: @MichaBerger That it is a subtype of gezeira shava is but one view.

Comment: @MichaBerger My whole point with that example is that it's an exception.

Comment: @Alex - What I was saying is that "an example" is a mis-speech and may mislead.

And if heqesh isn't taken as a g"sh, then where does it fit into the middos? Did R' Yishmael not codify them? (RY uses ribui umi'ut, even though they're on R' Aqiva's list and not his, and similarly v.v. -- RA uses kelal uperat.) I think that presenting heqesh in the context of middos shehaTorah nidrashes bahen, even with a one line "we don't know where in the taxonomy..." is an important part of knowing what it is.

Comment: @MichaBerger According to some it's not part of any list because it's considered explicit. I don't think that it is necessary to state every known fact/detail about hekeishim in order to address this particular question (and I did refer the reader to Encyclopedia Talmudit for a comprehensive discussion). The question here simply asks to explain the idea. The first part of my answer did that. The rest of my answer is a kind of disclaimer that the earlier part is only generally speaking, but there are some exceptions. The two types of exceptions I noted are most germane to my answer > cont.

Comment: @MichaBerger  < cont. because they show that a hekesh is not always a derivation and not always with two sequentially juxtaposed concepts, which are the two basic parts if the definition that I gave.

Answer (score 2):

(*I'm not adding anything new just making the point more sound*).

According to Kitzur Klalay Gmarah (brought at the end of Brochos on 13 Midos of R' Ishmoel and more) *a link needed, please*:
[image]

My poor translation of the selected text: "**We hold that an Heikesh can not be argued with, because we treat it as it was explicitly written in the Torah".**

Let me explain it by offering my "definition" of Heikesh:

> "Hekesh" is **a term (name) for a closed group of arguments, existing in the Talmudic time**, based on closeness of the text of the Torah either semantically or physically (Smuchot).

We don't know the history of the Heikeshim in the Talmud - whether they were  originally taught by Moses (הלכה למשה מסיני) or generated and systematized by Tanoim themselves, but **those are not rules by which new arguments can be constructed in any way.**

Especially for those who are new to study of Gemmorah, I suggest reading the whole chapter.

Answer (score 1):

In short, a hekesh is an instrument for deriving laws through similarities. When two verses (or phrases) are juxtaposed, we may be able to derive that all the laws that apply to one verse or phrase apply to the second verse or phrase as well. In general a hekesh will be identified either through actual juxtaposition of two ideas, or in some cases, through a verse that groups the two ideas together.

A hekesh cannot be used by laymen, nor by Rabbis. A hekesh must be learned through the Mesorah (otherwise halakha would be mayhem).

Comment: Justaposition, yes. But I thought using similarity between verses is the other kind of gezeira shava.

Answer (score 0):

Jastrow says it comes from the word meaning to clap things together (see entry for היקש). You do a hekesh when you draw information out of an apparent correspondence between words or clauses.